# How to check that i > 0 with try... catch?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I want to check that a variable (e.g "totalSum" is bigger than 0) with try catch, and if it isn't
I want the program to cancel and write out a message to the user.

Following code is by obvious reasons not possible to compile, but hopefully you see what I want with it:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        totalSum > 0;
        break;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total sum is too small.");
        End program
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this with try...catch and if so, how to do it?

Comment: You want an If/Else block, not a Try/Catch block.

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to do it via try & catch instead of using conditional logic?

Comment: Exceptions are quite expensive, comparatively, can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Exceptions should be thrown in abnormal situations only; `try/catch` construct is not the way to handle program flow.

Answer (score 4):

A *try/catch* block can do this:

```
try
{
    if (totalSum < 0)
        throw new ApplicationException();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Total sum is too small");
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

But a simple *if* statement can do this with a lot less work:

```
if (totalSum < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Total sum is too small");
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this, though I don't recommend it:

```
try
{
  if (totalSum < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("totalSum", "Total sum is too small.");
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: don't forget the 'exit' statement :)

Comment: Since the first trip through the "while" will either "break" or "exit", I would take out the while altogether. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can throw an exception

```
if (totalSum < 0)
{
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("totalSum");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not much reason to use try catch.

You can do

```
try {
    if(!(totalSum > 0)) throw new Exception();
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine("Total sum is too small.");
}
```

But really, no reason to do so - why do you have to use try..catch?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use a `try/catch` block here. Use exceptions for *exceptional circumstances only*. In your case, just use `if` and `else`:

```
if (totalSum > 0)
{
    // Good! Do something here
}
else
{
    // Bad! Tell the user
    Console.WriteLine("Bad user!");
}
```

Or, if you'd like to loop:

```
int totalSum = 0;
while (totalSum <= 0)
{
    totalSum = GetSum();
    if (totalSum <= 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Too small!");
}
```